# How to make each image on array tappable to execute different function on swift?

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, swift, ios8

I am trying to make a filter app. I have difficulty to make each image on array tappable, here is my code but it doesn't works:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!
var pageImages: [UIImage] = []
var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Set up the image you want to scroll & zoom and add it to the scroll view
    pageImages = [UIImage(named:"photo1.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo2.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo4.png")!,
        UIImage(named:"photo5.png")!]

    let pageCount = pageImages.count

    // Set up the page control
    pageControl.currentPage = 3
    pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount

    // Set up the array to hold the views for each page
    for _ in 0..<pageCount {
        pageViews.append(nil)
        var photoOne = pageImages[1]
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: photoOne)

        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "haha")
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    // Set up the content size of the scroll view
    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(58 * CGFloat(pageImages.count), pagesScrollViewSize.height)

    // Load the initial set of pages that are on screen
    loadVisiblePages()
}

func haha(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    println("This will be the filter effect")
}
func loadPage(page: Int) {

    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }

    // Load an individual page, first checking if you've already loaded it
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
    } else {
        var frame = scrollView.bounds
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0.0
        frame = CGRectInset(frame, -10.0, 10.0)

        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page])
        newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        newPageView.frame = frame
        scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)
        pageViews[page] = newPageView
    }
}

func purgePage(page: Int) {


    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }

    // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        pageView.removeFromSuperview()
        pageViews[page] = nil
    }

}

func loadVisiblePages() {

    // First, determine which page is currently visible
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 50.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 50.0)))

    // Update the page control
    pageControl.currentPage = page

    // Work out which pages you want to load
    let firstPage = page - 15
    let lastPage = page + 5


    // Purge anything before the first page
    for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }

    // Load pages in our range
    for var index = firstPage; index <= lastPage; ++index {
        loadPage(index)
    }

    // Purge anything after the last page
    for var index = lastPage+2; index < pageImages.count; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }
}


func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    // Load the pages that are now on screen
    loadVisiblePages()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Basically I took it from the article on the Ray Wenderlich website, I just added more picture and resize the picture. I'll be grateful if you can help me, thank you

Comment: I don't see you adding "imageView(s)" to UI anywhere?

Comment: I already added but I forgot to mention it on the code example, sorry @gagarwal

Comment: here is the new code example @gagarwal